# Uploader File uploads anything

Tags: php, file-upload

My Form is simple and I thought the uploading php was simple, but when i test it the results are unusual. I can upload any file and any size and it will Work. I thought i had written it to restrict certain files and sizes...Where am I going wrong?

Form:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

upload_file.php:

```
    $target = "uploads/"; 
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
    $ok = 1; 
    $uploaded = $_POST['uploaded'];
//This is our size condition 
    if ($uploaded_size > 3000){ 
        echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
        $ok=0; 
    } 

//This is our limit file type condition 
    if ($uploaded_type == "text/php"){ 
        echo "No PHP files are allowed for upload.<br>"; 
        $ok = 0; 
    } 

//Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
    if ($ok == 0){ 
        Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
    } 

//If everything is ok we try to upload it 
    else{ 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)){ 
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
        } 
        else{ 
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: where is you $uploaded_type and $uploaded_size var ?

Comment: here is a really simple clear article http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @Vector: Oh no, don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: Wow, good to know. I've always thought they were the W3C, and also thought the info was either too vague to be useful or flat out wrong. I hate it when they come up in search results. It would be nice to be able to thumbs down their results in your own browser to prevent their results displayed to you in the future...

Answer (score 3):

Your code is outright wrong. Nowhere do you define `$uploaded_size`, `$uploaded_type`, etc... so the code boils down to:

```
if ($uploaded_size > 3000 {
```

is equivalent to

```
if (0 > 3000) {  // undefined variables are typecast to 0
```

which evaluates to false, so `$ok` stays `1` and no error is triggered.

I **STRONGLY** suggest you read the PHP manpages on handling file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I thought the $uploaded_size & $uploaded_type was a predetermined php command.
Errr,...I'll go read it again.

Comment: IT seems to me to be very vague or way above my exp level. How can I learn it if the resources are all advanced? ::Frustrated::

Answer (score 1):

you need to use it like

```
     if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 3000) ...
```

or define $uploaded_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"] before the check. Also similarly you would need to use $_FILES["file"]["type"]

```
     $uploaded_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
     $uploaded_type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
     ...
```

Comment: "file" being the input name="uploaded" from my example above, correct?
so it would read $uploaded_type = $_FILES["uploaded"]["size"]

Comment: Do you know where i can find info on what types are available to designate? i.e. image/jpeg, text/php and so on...

Comment: if you search for mime types you can find more http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#87856 however it is better that you ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$target = "uploads/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok = 1; 
$uploaded = $_POST['uploaded'];
//This is our size condition 
if ($uploaded_size > 3000){ 
    echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
    $ok=0; 
} 

//This is our limit file type condition 
if ($uploaded_type == "text/php"){ 
    echo "No PHP files are allowed for upload.<br>"; 
    $ok = 0; 
} 

//Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
if ($ok == 0){ 
    Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
    die();
} 

//If everything is ok we try to upload it 
else{ 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)){ 
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been       uploaded"; 
    } 
    else{ 
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
        die();
    } 
}
```

Adding the `die()` function tells the code to stop. Also, where is your $uploaded_type and $uploaded_size var ?